# Using jquery.validate to validate submitted form based on which form is used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have two forms on a page, an update form and an add form, what I want to do is on submission of either form, pull the id of that form, along with the action, validate the particular form, then load the return from the webserver.

I got it to work by specifically using each form's id, but the js code is repeated twice, id prefer it to be a bit more dynamic.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>


<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="update">                
            <form action="php/update_level.php" method="post" id="form1">
                <h2>Update Level</h2>
                <label>Select Bag Level</label>
                <select id="target" name="levelSelect"> <option selected>Select</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach($result as $row)
                    {?>
                        <option><?php echo $row['Level'] ?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
                <div id="upForm">
                </div>
                <div class="message">

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="addNew">                
            <form action="php/add_level.php" id="form2">
                <h2>New Level</h2>    
                <label>Level</label>
                <input class="required" maxlength="10" minlenght="1" type="text" name="level" placeholder="Level">
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea class="required" name="description"  rows="3" placeholder="Description of level type"></textarea>  
                </br>
                <div class="message">

                </div>
                <div class="form-actions">
                <button id="inFormSub" type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>                   
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var id=$(this).attr('id');
var action=$(this).attr('action');

console.log(action + ' ' + id); //works outputs update_bag.php form1 on submit of form1
                                //add_bag.php form2 on submit of form2
$(id).validate({
    submitHandler: function() {


        console.log(action + ' ' + id); //doesnt work
        $(id).find('div.message').load(action, $(id).serializeArray());            
    }
});
```

JS that works

```
    $('#form1').validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
        var action = $('#form1').attr('action');

        console.log(action + ' validate1');
        $('#form2').find('div.message').load(action, $('#form1').serializeArray());            
    }
});    

$('#form2').validate({

    submitHandler: function() {
        var action = $('#form2').attr('action');

        console.log(action + ' validate2');
        $('#form2').find('div.message').load(action, $('#form2').serializeArray());            
    }
});
```

My knowledge of JS and Jquery is small at best, and im probably staring the solution right in the face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach to applying a plugin that requires specific data per element is to loop over the elements using `each()` so you can access `this` within the loop in order to easily access the individual form element without duplicating the code for each one

```
$('#form1,#form2').each(function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    var action = $form.attr('action');
    $form.validate({
        submitHandler: function() {           
            $form.find('div.message').load(action, $form.serializeArray());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the solution I eventually came to as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use on submitHandler the form variable and get the id and action

```
...
submitHandler: function(form){

    console.log($(form).attr('id'), $(form).attr('action'));    

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `$(this).attr("id")` call just returns the ID of the element, but that is not a propper css selector, so you need to add the hash sign youre self

try and change the call to:

```
$("#"+id).validate({
   //validate code here
})
```

Comment: A friend mentioned that when after i submitted, making the change causes it to fire off and pick up the correct id and action based of the form submitted, but the validate does not appear to be firing on the first click of submit. Maybe this will help: http://kick.hooplahosts.co.uk/fire/FireServiceProject/level.php